# Byte Order Mask: confusing the UTF encoding

Tags: unicode, utf-8, utf-16, byte-order-mark

The Byte Order Mask (BOM) uses the Unicode character U+FEFF to determine the encoding of a text file according to the following rule:

```
+-------------+-----------------------+
|    Bytes    |     Encoding Form     |
+-------------+-----------------------+
| 00 00 FE FF | UTF-32, big-endian    |
| FF FE 00 00 | UTF-32, little-endian |
| FE FF       | UTF-16, big-endian    |
| FF FE       | UTF-16, little-endian |
| EF BB BF    | UTF-8                 |
+-------------+-----------------------+
```

My question is: is there any combination of bytes that can make one UTF encoding to be confused with another UTF encoding?

For example, if I have a UTF-16 big-endian encoded file without BOM and with the characters U+EFBB and U+BF40 (EF BB BF 40) can it be confused with an UTF-8 encoded file with BOM and the ASCII character `@`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, without knowing the encoding, a sequence of U+0000 characters has an unknown length.

```
00 00 00 00  UTF-8   U+0000 U+0000 U+0000 U+0000     
00 00 00 00  UTF-16  U+0000 U+0000 
00 00 00 00  UTF-32  U+0000
```

BTW—Bytes that look like a byte order mark cannot be used to determine the encoding of a text file. In general, it's an unsolvable problem—data loss.

Comment: What do you mean with "Bytes that look like a byte order mark cannot be used to determine the encoding of a text file"?

Comment: I mean that starting with only the knowledge that a file is a text file and examining the bytes, only gets you to the point of saying hundreds of encodings are valid and some aren't. Having bytes that look like a BOM doesn't change that much.  If you start with the knowledge that a file is a text file with one of the Unicode encodings, then yes, if a BOM is present, you can use it to distinguish among the Unicode encodings. But, it's hard to imagine when you would have all that knowledge and also not know which encoding it is (and therefore wouldn't need the BOM for _that_ purpose).

Comment: "it's hard to imagine when you would have all that knowledge and also not know which encoding it is" are you saying that the BOM is almost useless?

Comment: No. A BOM lets an encoding library to be told that the encoding is UTF-16 or UTF-32 and it can detect the byte order from the BOM.

Comment: Ok, that's true. But I still don't understand how to solve cases like the one I presented in the description. Is there a way?

Comment: Yes, if you have "a UTF-16 big-endian encoded file" tell that to whomever you give the file to; then they won't have to ask or try guessing by reading with UTF-8.

Comment: So if I want to write a program that accept a text in any UTF form, and with or without BOM, I can&#39;t prevent overlapping situations, right? I must live together with this possible "problems"

Comment: As I said, in general, there is no general solution. There are some specific types of text files (JSON, HTML, XML) that have standards that solve these problems (and, of course, many others that aren't text files). If you have users that are willing to use text files but unwilling to indicate the encoding they have chosen, why would they comply with your expectation that it is one of the Unicode encodings?

Answer (score 0):

The BOM is designed to find the byte order when the size is known. So there is no `U+FFFE` code.  There is no further limitation on charset, so there can be some overlapping codes. (@TomBlodget has an example of a "degenerate" case)

BOM in UTF-8 is not really needed, but it should be preserved, in order to do a perfect round conversion from other unicode encoding. Just Windows started to use it to distinguish UTF-8 from other encoding (especially outside unicode encoding), and that it is not 100% reliable.

`C0` and `C1` are bytes not allowed on UTF-8, along various sequences (first bits on byte 1 defines the length of sequence, and so there should be exactly so many bytes with "continuation prefix" (`0b10`). So usually it is easy to find if a string it is UTF-8 (if not too short or "degenerate").

UTF-32 has valid values just from `0` to `U+10FFFF`, so this could be used to distinguish it from UTF16 (again, "degenerate" and short strings are not discriminable, OTOH we should expect very often `00 00` in UTF32, and usually no `00 00` on UTF16 *normal* text, but ev. at the end.).

Control characters and private character set should not be used on "public" Unicode text (but if you agree on the protocol, but so that should not be the case of the question).

Comment: C0 is certainly valid ASCII, which means it is also valid UTF-8, by definition

Comment: @JoelFan • What Unicode code point generates a `C0` byte for a valid UTF-8 encoding unit sequence?  ASCII is a 7-bit encoding, with values from `00` to `7F`.

Comment: Ooops. My comment (now deleted) mixed `C0` as byte in answer, to C0 as control block 0 (possibly because I just answered something on that kind). My bad.

Comment: Bytes `C0` and `C1` are not allowed on correct UTF-8: the interpretation will get overlong encoding (so encoded with more bytes as needed). There is just some cases (Modified UTF-8) where `C0 80` is used (instead the correct `00`): The reason is about strings defined in C language: zero terminated. But an Unicode string may contain correctly a `00`. It is just a trick, which should be only used internally in a program (not to exchange data).